# How to solve $3^x=3-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Is it possible to solve for $$3^x=3-x$$ **without graphing** it?

*This question is in the section: Solving Exponential equations in my math textbook.*

I have tried to log both sides and solve for it however that just leads me back to the original equation.

Comment: Thank you sir. I like your feedback. Pardon me if I did not follow format, english is not my first language. I hope sir you understand.

Comment: Have you tried to solve $3^x + x = 3$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let consider

$$f(x)=3^x-(3-x)$$

and note that

- $f(0)=-2$
- $f(1)=1$

therefore by IVT there is a solution in $(0,1)$.

Can you show that this is the unique solution?

Comment: If I am correct then: for $x>1$ the term $3^x +x$ is more positive than '3' everywhere in that domain. Also, for x<0 the term $-3+x$ is more negative to be neutralized by $3^x$ as $3^x$ will then become in postive fraction number.

Comment: @jayant98 We can consider the sign of $f'(x)=3^x \log 3 +1$.

Comment: Yes Sir! Another way which is more simple and effective.

Comment: @jayant98 Call me simply gimusi! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The solution can be expressed in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). In general, graphing is not a way of "solving" an equation because it cannot give you an exact solution. Graphing the equations above will help you approximate $x \approx 0.742$ but cannot give you an exact value.